# Adding images on both sides of a div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to ask, how to add two images on both sides of a div.

See, I got a main container on my site, and I'd like to add a little decoration on both sides, like a shadow which would foreground the actual content and place less emphasis on the background, y'know?

So, I got something like this:

page.html

```html
...
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="shadow-left"></div>
    <div id="shadow-right"></div>
    
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</body>
...
```

main.css

```css
...

#container {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 840px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#shadow-left {
  // Gotta do that on the left site too
}

#shadow-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px; // So there's a little space just for the upper nav
  left: 840px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('/res/img/shadow-right.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

...
```

I imagined it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Mgq.jpg), but there's just NOTHING. How could I accomplish to do that?

Comment: So the image you showed. In that white part is representing your Container?

Comment: Are you asking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/4kqf97nq/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7ejxwdqy/) is a fiddle where the main content is under-shadowed by whatever color you'd like, you can expand the shadow effect by playing around with the css and I'm sure there are plenty of css-shadow generators online. Hope this is what you're looking for.

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
    width:60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:green;
    height:1000px;
    box-shadow: 30px 0 19px -4px lightgreen, -30px 0 19px -4px lightgreen;
}
```

P.S. Excuse the green..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for this you can use floats, I hope I am understanding your question correctly.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L4cjz8p9/

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="shadow-left"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x300"></div>
    <div id="shadow-right"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x300"></div>
    Main content
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#shadow-left
{
    float:left;
}

#shadow-right
{
    float:right;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 840px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to position things outside e.g. a centered container. You could then fill the "shadows" with a background that repeats only over y or no repeat at all if you only would like to have something on the top of the page but not repeat when you scroll down.

The example here just has a 50px wide box at both sides next to the container.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/60yjen0a/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="shadow left"></div>
    <div class="shadow right"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.shadow {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 50px;
}
.left {
    left: -50px;
}
.right {
    right: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With absolute position you can use `left` and `right`

```
#shadow-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px; 
  left: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: YOUR_BACKGROUND_URL_FOR_LEFT_SHADOW;
}

#shadow-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px; 
  right: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: YOUR_BACKGROUND_URL_FOR_RIGHT_SHADOW;
}
```

Check this on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ok148hrh/3/)